# What's the correct file to store environmental variables for zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh, environment-variables

I'm a bit confused as to how all of this works. Seemingly every tutorial tells me something different. So far there's about 4 different files I can add environmental variables to:

`.zshrc`

`.profile`

`.zprofile`

`.zshenv`

Which file should I be adding environmental variables to? So far I've got variables in all of them, along with other things like aliases.

Does it really matter, or is there a proper standard to follow?

Edit: Question closed due to it being 'opinion-based'. To clarify, please only provide factual answers, and not opinions.

Comment: The initial version of the answer you got actually was just stating an opinion :-)

Comment: There is no need to dig into tutorials for this: Just do a `man zshall` and search for the section labelled _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_. From this you learn which files are processed under which circumstances by zsh (it helps drawing a diagram of the different cases on a sheet of paper), and then you will see, where you want to place which definitions, so that it suits best. Mostly, you will distinguish 4 cases: non-interactive login shell, non-interacitve non-login shell, interacitve login shell, interactive non-login shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a standard as defined in the zsh manual https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files

Unfortunately Apple did not read them fully and so for macOS there is a slight difference. Or they tried to provide adding to path only for login sessions but their solution path_helper messes up what the user sets in .zshenv.

The file that the variables in differs as the files are read differently depending on how the shell is launched.

So given the files you list

### .profile

Nothing to do with zsh - it is the one file that sh reads. (bash will read this as a login shell if there is no .bash_profile

### .zshenv

This file is read by all zsh shells when they start. So any common environment variable should be here.
This include $PATH if you follow the zsh manual; however Apple did not read that and in /etc/zshrc which is read after that they add to and reorder the $PATH

This file is read by scripts.

> `.zshenv` is sourced on all invocations of the shell, unless the -f option is set. It should contain commands to set the command search path, plus other important environment variables. `.zshenv` should not contain commands that produce output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.

### .zprofile and .zlogin

Called at login - this is on each Terminal on macOS but only once on other Unixes

> `.zlogin` is sourced in login shells. It should contain commands that should be executed only in login shells. `.zlogout` is sourced when login shells exit. `.zprofile` is similar to `.zlogin`, except that it is sourced before `.zshrc`. `.zprofile` is meant as an alternative to `.zlogin` for ksh fans; the two are not intended to be used together, although this could certainly be done if desired.
>
> `.zlogin` is not the place for alias definitions, options, environment variable settings, etc.; as a general rule, it should not change the shell environment at all. Rather, it should be used to set the terminal type and run a series of external commands (fortune, msgs, etc).

### .zshrc

This is read in an interactive shell ie when you run the shell to type things in.

> `.zshrc` is sourced in interactive shells. It should contain commands to set up aliases, functions, options, key bindings, etc.

Also in macOS this is the simplest place to alter the $PATH to correct the order that Apple changes with /usr/libexec/path_helper as your change is in one place - however if you want to be complete you can fix path_helper chnages in ~/.zlogin but you would also then need to add your changes in $PATH in another file for non interactive runs as well).

Comment: Certainly sheds some light for me on a most confusing area. I only have `.zshrc`, none of the others. Is that bad? Also, I don't have `/etc/path_helper` (macOS 12.2).

Comment: Sorry I did that from memory and got it wrong I have edited the correct path /usr/libexec/path_helper

Comment: Thank you for this. The clears some stuff up for me. I feel like I need to do a course on all this kind of stuff, as my knowledge is clearly lacking when it comes to shells etc

Comment: @AaronWright No need for a course. Just learn to read the manuals, for may Unix things especially older ones they are complete. Videos and blogs are often produced by those who do not fully understand the issues and so many are wrong - unfortunately you have to know the issues to be able to see which blogs etc are useful as there is no editing or other quality assurance on the web. Books are likely to be more accurate but even then I suspect many are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping in line with standards in Bash and `.bashrc`, you can feel safe storing environment variables for zsh in `.zshrc`.

Official explanation of load order and purpose of dotfiles are in the zsh man:

**STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES**

```
       Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this  cannot  be  overridden. 
       Subsequent behaviour is modified by the RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options; the former affects all startup files, while the second only affects  global startup  files  (those  shown here with an path starting with a /).  If one of the options is  unset  at  any  point,  any  subsequent  startup file(s)  of the corresponding type will not be read.  It is also possible for a file in  $ZDOTDIR  to  re-enable  GLOBAL_RCS.  Both  RCS  and GLOBAL_RCS are set by default.

       Commands  are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.  If the shell is a login
       shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile  and  then  $ZDOTDIR/.zpro-
       file.   Then,  if  the  shell  is  interactive,  commands are read from
       /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.  Finally, if the shell is a  login
       shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.

       When  a  login  shell  exits,  the  files  $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout  and  then
       /etc/zlogout are read.  This happens with either an explicit  exit  via
       the exit or logout commands, or an implicit exit by reading end-of-file
       from the terminal.  However, if the shell terminates  due  to  exec'ing
       another  process,  the  logout  files  are  not  read.   These are also
       affected by the RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options.  Note  also  that  the  RCS
       option  affects  the saving of history files, i.e. if RCS is unset when
       the shell exits, no history file will be saved.

       If ZDOTDIR is unset, HOME is used instead.  Files listed above as being
       in /etc may be in another directory, depending on the installation.

       As /etc/zshenv is run for all instances of zsh, it is important that it
       be kept as small as possible.  In particular, it is a good idea to  put
       code  that does not need to be run for every single shell behind a test
       of the form `if [[ -o rcs ]]; then ...' so that it will not be executed
       when zsh is invoked with the `-f' option.

       Any  of  these files may be pre-compiled with the zcompile builtin com-
       mand (see zshbuiltins(1)).  If a compiled file exists  (named  for  the
       original  file plus the .zwc extension) and it is newer than the origi-
       nal file, the compiled file will be used instead.
```

**FILES**

- `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin`
- `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogout`
- `${TMPPREFIX}*   (default is /tmp/zsh*)`
- `/etc/zshenv`
- `/etc/zprofile`
- `/etc/zshrc`
- `/etc/zlogin`
- `/etc/zlogout    (installation-specific - /etc is the default)`

Comment: Perfect thank you. My question was closed because it was `opinion-based` (which is incorrect). Thankfully you answered it in time :) I searched the manual but couldn't find anything on this. Searching again, I found it.

Comment: -1 as zsh is not bash - it has an **improved order of startup files** 
 The correct place for many environment variables is ~/.,zshenv zsh is clearer what the files are for. Also ~/.zshrc is not called in all cases

Comment: `zsh` has an **improved** order?  Hardly.  `zsh` takes what `bash` does and makes it worse.  Far worse.

Comment: It is clear to me that semantic file naming for environment variables in zshenv versus bash lacking bashenv as a standard practice, I would objectively call tht an improvement over bash. As to the ordering, would you mind sharing @MarcWilson as to your ideal order and reasoning? I'm here to learn from other developers, especially if we disagree and I assume I may be wrong.

Comment: Zsh needs all of zshenv/zprofile/zshrc?  Hardly.  Even bash does not claim to need to replace .profile with a file of its own, even while its developer thinks it needs to have different startup files for login vs non-login shells.

Comment: @MarcWilson Understandably that it doesn't "need" them, but it's in the manpages and there must be reasons for such. Following the ZSH developers' own guidance, I answered the question, no opinion included. I was asking for your ideal order and some reasoning, and you seem to have simply given more dogma, I'd still like to get the background and anecdotes behind your conclusions here so that we can record some productive knowledge for future readers of this thread. Is that too much to ask for?

Comment: @AaronWright I'm confused why you commented that my answer was sufficient, then accepted the other answer that just restates the same things I said.

Comment: Ws just slightly more detailed