$PROMPT $PS1 automatically set in zsh
I changed from bash to zsh on a mac upgrade and now cannot change my terminal settings. As I moved from an old to new machine, which inherited the old settings.
Opening a new terminal gives:
Last login: Thu Apr 25 17:26:59 on ttys000
PROMPT='%m:%1~ %n%#'
~ % PROMPT='%m:%1~ %n%#'
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~ cws%


When the last line in my .zshrc is:
PROMPT='%/ %# '
PS1='%F{blue}%~ %(?.%F{green}.%F{red})%#%f '

I assume that PROMPT is being sourced from another file, but cannot see where by searching. Does anyone know in which order the bash_rc profile type files are sourced when opening a terminal?

OK, fixed, its if you have a hard setting in the terminal preferences app (in setting, profiles, shell, run command.
I will leave this issue up in case anyone else gets this error.

Welcome to Ask Different! Please put an answer below as this will get culled by the robots if no answer arrives and it’s unlikely to get votes without answer too

Also you say it is in zsh but your last question says bash_rcFor zsh file order see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436318/237

To see which files are sourced on zsh startup, depends on the kind of shell. You can find the rules for this in the section STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES in the zsh man-page. If you add the -x switch to the command which invokes your zsh, you can actually follow what files are sourced.

BTW, your code does not make much sense: PS1 and PROMPT are "tied" variables, i.e. two names for the same entity. If you set PS1, you automatically change PROMPT, and vice versa. So setting both is pointless. This is documented in the section PARAMETERS USED BY THE SHELL in the man page.
